# XAMPP mysql won't start on my Mac all of a sudden

Tags: xampp, homebrew

I've been using XAMPP on my mac for over a year and a half now and to allow the mysql to start i had to quit mysqld through the activiity monitor and then it worked perfectly. Now all of a sudden Mysql wont start on XAMPP and whenever I try quitting/ force quitting it through the activity monitor it only stays closed for a few seconds(not enough for the XAMPP to start), I also installed the latest mysql_client 8.0 from homebrew but nothing changed. Below are the stats from the activity monitor.

```
/opt/homebrew/var/mysql
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.1.0/bin/mysqld
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.1.0/lib/plugin/component_reference_cache.so
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/73.2/lib/libicuio.73.2.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libevent/2.1.12_1/lib/libevent_openssl-2.1.7.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libevent/2.1.12_1/lib/libevent_pthreads-2.1.7.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libevent/2.1.12_1/lib/libevent_core-2.1.7.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libevent/2.1.12_1/lib/libevent_extra-2.1.7.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/zlib/1.3/lib/libz.1.3.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/lz4/1.9.4/lib/liblz4.1.9.4.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/73.2/lib/libicuuc.73.2.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.4/lib/libssl.3.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/zstd/1.5.5/lib/libzstd.1.5.5.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/protobuf@21/21.12/lib/libprotobuf-lite.3.21.12.0.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/73.2/lib/libicui18n.73.2.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.4/lib/libcrypto.3.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/73.2/lib/libicudata.73.2.dylib
/dev/null
/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/Nadas-Mac.local.err
/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/Nadas-Mac.local.err
count=0, state=0xa
/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/binlog.index
/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/#ib_16384_0.dblwr
/private/var/folders/pb/yss9__v55llf6rh3k_k2bv300000gn/T/ibQE8DMq
/private/var/folders/pb/yss9__v55llf6rh3k_k2bv300000gn/T/ibQSZv37
/private/var/folders/pb/yss9__v55llf6rh3k_k2bv300000gn/T/ibipI3DH
/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/#ib_16384_1.dblwr
/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/ibdata1
/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/#innodb_redo/#ib_redo849
/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/ibtmp1
/private/var/folders/pb/yss9__v55llf6rh3k_k2bv300000gn/T/ibuRfNnC
/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/undo_001
/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/undo_002
/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/mysql.ibd
count=0, state=0xa
localhost:33060
/tmp/mysqlx.sock
localhost:mysql
/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/binlog.059607
/tmp/mysql.sock
/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/#innodb_temp/temp_1.ibt
/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/#innodb_temp/temp_2.ibt
/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/#innodb_temp/temp_3.ibt
/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/#innodb_temp/temp_4.ibt
/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/#innodb_temp/temp_5.ibt
/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/#innodb_temp/temp_6.ibt
/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/#innodb_temp/temp_7.ibt
/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/#innodb_temp/temp_8.ibt
/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/#innodb_temp/temp_9.ibt
/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/#innodb_temp/temp_10.ibt
```

Even after checking the Brew doctor function in terminal , nothing came up except that my old SQL_client has depreciated so I changed it into their other version 8.0.